# Paypal IPN : Why do I have to verify every time a payment is made?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using paypal as a payment method on my page. I am using IPN.

Problem is: Everytime a payment is made, I have tu MANUALLY approve it on Paypal. Therefore, Paypal is always sending back "Pending" to my listener. After I manually approve it, it sends "completed" to my listener.

I have been testing that for ages in sandbox and it worked like a charm. But why do I ave to manually approve it in live mode? My script won't work that way.

Help is appreciated :)

Pic:

[image: paypal ipn]

Bye

Comment: What kind of payments are being made? Are they for orders? Or is someone just sending you money?

Comment: Are you using web payment, express checkout or anything?

Comment: I am using express. User clicks "pay now" on my page and gets redirected to paypal and sent back after payment. I am passing hidden fields in the form where the user clicks on "pay now".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be something you have to contact Paypal about or a configuration setting under your profile. I get orders daily and never have to "APPROVE" an order. Perhaps you are testing an echeck payment method in the sandbox.

Comment: I am not in the sandbox, I am live testing it with a friend. he is paying via his paypal balance

Comment: perhaps post a pic of the "approval" part so I can see

Comment: Try this: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sending-and-receiving-money/Unclaimed-funds/td-p/297870?profile.language=en-gb

Comment: Thanks, I had to change the currency options to accept payments of any currency.